# bootstrap whitespace gap between navbar and jumbotron. margin css doesn't fix the issue

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

[image]

In the above photo, you can see the tiny amount of whitespace circled. There also appears to be a border-radius on the jumbotron element and I am trying to get this to show without any gaps.. Below is my code.

```
<div class="container">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark border">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="">Home</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
      <div class="navbar-nav">
        <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">About<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Portfolio</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Blog</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="jumbotron image_test ">
    <h1 class="p-5 text-white">test</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would appreciate any help in fixing this. I have tried setting the margin-bottom of the classes to 0px.. and it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: if you set style="margin:0 !important" on <nav>, does it work? – Vega 33 mins ago

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove the rounding on the jumbrotron, use **`rounded-0`**:

```
<div class="jumbotron image_test rounded-0"></div>
```

To remove the whitespace *below* the navbar, use **`border-bottom-0`**:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark border border-bottom-0">
..
</nav>
```

To remove *all* of the whitespace around the navbar remove the **`border`** class:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
..
</nav>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/PlPt1mLBfH

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You are having a border class on the **nav** tag, removing that may solve the issue and also decrease the `border-radius` on **`.jumbotron`**